# Visual Studio - Create an Item Template that shows up in the Add New Item dialog for the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, new-item

Visual Studio 2017

I created an Item Template for Visual Studio. When installing the template or running the solution locally, the template only shows up in the **Add New Item** dialog for a C# project.

I want it to be in the **Add New Item** dialog for the solution.

It seems to me the problem is having the ProjectType set to CSharp in the .vstemplate file, but I don't know what to set it to. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/projecttype-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2017#text-value) the options are only CSharp, VisualBasic, and Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio - Create an Item Template that shows up in the Add New Item dialog for the solution

Item template/Project template are for projects rather than solutions and belongs to a specific type of project (such as C# library), that is the reason why you could not add Item template to the solution.

When you add a new item to a solution using Visual Studio, you'll only see those items that are in **General Category**. All those files are not "templates", they can be find here :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\NewFileItems
```

So, if you want to add New Item dialog for the solution, you could add your custom file, like, `Test.py`, then restart the Visual Studio to add the new item for solution:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. This makes sense, and it works. Something I didn't mention in the original question is that I want to be able to publish this to the Visual Studio Marketplace so others can install/use it; on twitter I was given a lead from Visual Studio on how to achieve this.

Comment: After talking to [Mads Kristensen](https://twitter.com/mkristensen), it is not possible to publish a solution-level Item Template to the Marketplace.